# Simple multiprocessing code, doesn't call callback

Tags: python, multithreading

I have that simple code, and it doesn't call the pipeline function at all
I don't know where is the problem, the function is not called, is it a problem of importing those stuff ? There is a tensorflow import that is a class that uses it

```
import numpy as np
import time
import Sort_Algorithm
import cv2
import os
import argparse
import helpers
import detector
import json

from collections import defaultdict
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib.path import Path
import time
import datetime
from interaction import (Behavior, Interaction, select_slice,
                                 CODE_DEFAULT, CODE_MSG, CODE_RES)
import asyncio

from geom import Region, compute_max_polygon_diagonal
from  parameter import RawParameterProcessor
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from collections import deque


from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue



def pipeline():
    while True:
        print("hello")

def main():

    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    for i in range(0,10):
         pool.apply_async(pipeline, args = (i))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: Seems most of those imports are not relevant to the question - please read [mcve]. Where/what is the callback? What makes you think *it* is not executing?

Comment: you can remove all the imports and it won't work... it doesn't print hello

Comment: Why do you `import Queue` and then not put anything into it? What example were you trying to follow that led you to code this?

Comment: You're not using `asyncio` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are doing good.

It seems the issue is that it silently failed.

I have used this simplify code of yours:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue


def pipeline(i):
    while True:
        print("hello")


def main():

    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    for i in range(0, 10):
        pool.apply_async(pipeline, args=(i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

I have changed two things, `args` parameter in `apply_async` is now a tuple, the function `pipeline` takes correctly the given parameter by defining it in its function declaration.

```
pool.apply_async(pipeline, args=(i))
# to 
pool.apply_async(pipeline, args=(i,))
```

and:

```
def pipeline():
    while True:
        print("hello")
# to
def pipeline(i):
    while True:
        print("hello")
```

If you don't need at all the parameter in pipeline, you can also write the following code (we don't pass any parameter):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue


def pipeline():
    while True:
        print("hello")


def main():

    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    for i in range(0, 10):
        pool.apply_async(pipeline)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Have a lovely day.

G

---

OP mentioned a callback but was not using one. This extends the toy example to use a callback and gather the results from the `apply_async` calls.

```
def pipeline(i):
    return i*2

def cb(n):
    print(f'foo: {n}')

def main():

    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    results= []

    for i in range(0,8):
         results.append(pool.apply_async(pipeline, args=(i,), callback=cb))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results
if __name__ == "__main__":

    results = main()
    print([result.get() for result in results])
```

Which *prints*:

```
foo: 0
foo: 2
foo: 4
foo: 6
foo: 8
foo: 10
foo: 12
foo: 14
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed,  we can also completely remove it, I am going to update the answer !

Comment: Mind if I add something?

Comment: Not at all, feel free :) !